# infix to postfix converter output issues

Tags: java, infix-notation, shunting-yard

I'm trying to implement an infix to postfix converter but I'm having some trouble with the output namely with parenthesis. When I try to pass in anything with parenthesis say something like:

```
(1*2*3^1)
```

I get a NoSuchElementException. Anyone know what's wrong?

Some notes: I'm passing in a deque of tokenized strings as the infix (so I'm restricted to deque methods) and returning a String deque of the postfix. Any help is appreciated.

**Here's my method in question:**

```
private static Deque<String>shuntingYard(Deque<String> infixQ){
  Deque<String> opS = new LinkedList<String>();
  Deque<String> outputQ = new LinkedList<String>();
  String token;
  while(!infixQ.isEmpty()){
     token = infixQ.removeFirst();
     if(isNumeric(token) || isAlpha(token)){
        outputQ.addLast(token);
     }
     if(token.equals("(")){
        opS.addFirst(token);
     }
     if(token.equals(")")){
        opS.addFirst(token);
        while(!outputQ.peekFirst().equals("(")){
              outputQ.addLast(opS.removeFirst());
        }
        opS.removeFirst();
     }

     if(isOperator(token)){
         while(!opS.isEmpty() && !(opS.peekFirst().equals("(") && prec(token) <= prec(opS.peekFirst()))){ 
           outputQ.addLast(opS.removeFirst());
        }
        opS.addFirst(token);
     }       
   }
   while(!opS.isEmpty()){
     outputQ.addLast(opS.removeFirst());
   }
   return outputQ;
}
```

Comment: Show us the stacktrace and indicate the line the error occurs on.

Comment: This line in particular:  outputQ.addLast(opS.removeFirst()); in the third if statement.

Comment: This is is what the stack prints out before the NoSuchElementException: stack:(
stack:*
stack:*

Comment: Nvm figured it out. For anyone curious, turns out the issue was with referencing the outputQ instead of the opS in the while loop (in the third if statement).